# Regex usage in C# to extract various pattern combinations

Tags: c#, .net, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to use regex.match to extract various patterns from a given string. I have 3 patterns which i have to match and extract respectively.

1st Pattern : Starts with a string of alphabets, then followed by numbers only

2nd Pattern : Starts with a string of alphabets, then followed by numbers, and then a string of alphabets only

3rd Pattern : Start with a number, then followed by a string of alphabets only

I have tried to use:

Regex.Match(inputData, @"^(\w+)(\d+)$") // 1st Pattern

Regex.Match(inputData, @"^(\w+)(\d+)(\w+)$") // 2nd Pattern

Regex.Match(inputData, @"^(\d+)(\w+)$") // 3rd Pattern

However, i have realized that 'w' can refer to a digit or an alphabet (which will give me false positive results) if the string supplied is invalid. I would really appreciate some help on fixing the pattern matching.

Thanks

Comment: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx, use [a-zA-Z]+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `(\w+)` with the following in your patterns:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)
```

This will only include the standard alphabet letters, and not the numbers. Note that if your requirements include also other characters - like accented letters - the above pattern will not match them.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like homework. If you want to impress your teacher you will read the wikipedia article on regular expressions.

You will pay particular attention to the section about character classes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Character_classes

Good luck!